# Imap Fetch Command

Tags: c#, imap

I am using the following C# code retrieve the header of messages, but I want to modify it so it can tell me if the message contains any Attachments, however I do  not want to load the complete message with attachments

```
var command = string.Format("FETCH {0} (FLAGS UID BODY[HEADER])", i);
Clean();
SendCommand(command);
var sizeLine = ReadLine();
```

I've tried the following

This retrieves the complete message or simply don't work, I am also working from the rfc website but can't seem to find the command for it

```
var command = string.Format("FETCH {0} (FLAGS UID BODY.PEEK[])", i);
var command = string.Format("FETCH {0} (FLAGS UID BODY[])", i);
var command = string.Format("FETCH {0} (FLAGS UID BODY[HEADER,MIME])", i);
var command = string.Format("FETCH {0} (FLAGS UID BODY[MIME])", i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `UID FETCH ... BODYSTRUCTURE`. Once you've seen the response, you may wish to consider using a library to do the parsing for you. There are at least two candidates on C#, MailKit and something called, IIRC, mailsystem.net. Try mailkit first.

Comment: I already have parsing correct :), will try this piece of command, I thought I completed my Imap Library but noticed I couldn't display the  GridView to show which mails have attachments and which not, unless I fetched the complete mail message

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to put UID before the FETCH command:

```
string tag = GetTag();
string response = SendCommandGetResponse(tag + "UID FETCH " + uid + " (BODY" +
                    (seen ? null : ".PEEK") + "[HEADER])", false);
```

coming from the [S22  ImapClient.cs](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap/blob/master/ImapClient.cs)

Comment: No the UID should be there where I've put it then I get the following Result, 
    "* 36 FETCH (FLAGS (\\Recent) UID 707 BODY[HEADER] {1657}\r\n"
on that when I fetch the complete message with body from the server I use UID FETCH 707 BODY[]

Comment: SendCommand(string.Format("UID FETCH {0} (FLAGS UID BODY[])", message.Uid));